# Fade out edges of repeating radial gradient in CSS

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I'm using a `repeating-radial-gradient` to create a dotted background effect. However, I need to fade the top and bottom edges to an opacity of 0 without knowing what the background color is. Is there any way to do this with CSS that works in IE 11+?

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
.dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, #02fcb8 0px, #02fcb8 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Need to turn this:

[image: Original]

Into this:

[image: After]

I can use an image mask, but there's no support in IE/Edge:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(1, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible using just CSS; however, I found a way to do this with an SVG using a `linearGradient` in a `mask` element and an SVG pattern:

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
.dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.dots svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots">
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <linearGradient id="grad" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" offset="0"/>
        <stop stop-color="white" offset="0.5"/>
        <stop stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
       </linearGradient>
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
      </mask>
      <pattern id="dots" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="1" style="stroke: none; fill: #02fcb8" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: url(#dots); mask: url(#mask)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I need something similiar, but also the radius of the dots should change with the gradient. (So largest circles at the bottom, small circles at the top). Can't really find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

**Fade the top edge**

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
.dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, #02fcb8 0px, #02fcb8 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 18px 18px;
  position:relative;
}
.dots:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

**Fade the top and bottom edges**

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
.dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, #02fcb8 0px, #02fcb8 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 18px 18px;
}
.dots:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, transparent 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fade the dots though, and if the background is changed then it no longer works. The reason I need to fade the dots is because the background won't actually be a solid color, it'll be an image that is changing.

Comment: Hi,see this https://jsfiddle.net/aey3n4Lc/1/ .I think dots get fade now even if changes the background image.